# Vkontakte sdk_fingerprint is incorrect only on random devices

Tags: fingerprint, vk

When the user of our application tries to login using VKontakte, he gots white screen with     `"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"sdk_fingerprint is     incorrect"`
The main problem is that not every users device gets this issue but only random devices. It works normally on some devices but on the others we got this result.
And the last is that if we distribute our release apk by another source (Skype, Telegram, etc) the problem disappears. 
So to summarize. The problem appears only when we distribute by Play Market and only on part of devices.

I have tried to:
1. paste release SHA-1 from Google Play Console to VKontakte app Console;
2. paste retrieved by `VKUtil.getCertificateFingerprint(this, this.getPackageName());` 
3. retrieve SHA-1 from console and paste to VK Console

We expect it must work on every device while Play Market distribution

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by copy and paste all the keys to VK Console and removed all colon `:` symbols. Be attentive! Do not remove anything else.